# Failed to upload a screen shot on questions?

Tags: discussion, imgur

I tried to upload a screen shot of error message with 4Mb capacity using image link, but failed. How I will solve this problem?

Comment: There is no need to make a full screen 2000 by 1400 pixel high-definition and upload it, when a 640 by 480 pixel scoped screenshhot is just as fine. Even better, copy the error message by selecting with the mouse and copy it to your question.

Comment: You need 10 reputation points to add images to posts (though they can still be uploaded, I think). That said, an error is best included as text copy-pasted into the question, as Johannes says.

Answer (score 7):

Ask yourself whether the full resolution image is actually necessary... in most cases it's probably not.

There is a limit to the file size that can be uploaded using the native IMGUR uploader on Stack Exchange. [It's roughly 2MB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133138/168244) as suggested by the upload dialog:

[image]

Reduce the file size in an external program before uploading.

Also, users are inherently throttled in their participation depending on their reputation. More reputation leads to more [privileges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) which leads to more freedom (and responsibility). While this doesn't relate to image size, such limitations hopefully educates the community in terms of the suggested site behaviour.

Related:

- [Resizing an image in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/168244)
- ["framing is not allowed" error when uploading gif file](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234591/168244)
- [Please do something to encourage people to scale down their giant heavyweight photos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101439/168244)